# Conservation of Four-Momentum for Photons

Tags: special-relativity

Consider a relativistic collision between an electron and a positron, that produces two photons.
Now, the absolute value of the momentum-four-vector $4m_0^2$ of the electron and the positron has to be conserved during this collision. However, the absolute value of the total momentum of the two photons after the collision is zero. How can that be?

Comment: Related http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123039/conservation-of-4-momentum-in-special-relativity

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how exactly you're getting the $4$ in front of $m^2$... It seems to me that what you're calculating is the sum of the squares, but what must be conserved is the square of the sum. Suppose the electron and positron come in with four-momentum $p_1$ and $p_2$, and the photons leave with momentum $k_1$ and $k_2$. You're asserting (I think) that

$$p_1^2 + p_2^2 = k_1^2 + k_2^2$$

But this is not true; what must be conserved is the **total** four-momentum (and therefore its square), so

$$(p_1+p_2)^2 = (k_1+k_2)^2$$
$$ p_1^2 + p_2^2 + 2 p_1\cdot p_2 = k_1^2 + k_2^2 + 2 k_1\cdot k_2$$
$$ 2m^2 + 2p_1\cdot p_2 = 2k_1\cdot k_2$$

And this last equation can be satisfied with appropriate choices for all the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

In the center-of-mass frame the two photons go in exactly opposite directions, hence conserving momentum (0 before, 0 after). They happen to have precisely the energy they need to preserve energy.